# Unable to control fan speed on NZXT

Tags: 22.04, fan

I'm unable to find a way to control the multiple fans on my new NZXT computer (Ubuntu 22.04). I have tried the common method of using `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol`, but have been unsuccessful. After completing the setup with `sudo sensors-detect`, I run `sudo pwmconfig`, and answer "y" to the question "Are you sure that you want to setup this output for manual control?" for each of the fans, I get this message:

```
Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon3/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon3/fan2_input     current speed: 2163 RPM
   hwmon3/fan3_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon3/fan4_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon3/fan5_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon3/fan6_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon3/fan7_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
```

Note that I don't hear any increase in fan speed when it does this. Also, it says that most of my fans are at 0RPM, but I can see that they are spinning.

Then comes the process of cycling through each fan to test the controls. Each time I get the following message (speeds vary though):

```
Testing pwm control hwmon3/pwm1 ...
  hwmon3/fan2_input ... speed was 2163 now 2177
    no correlation

No correlations were detected.
There is either no fan connected to the output of hwmon3/pwm1,
or the connected fan has no rpm-signal connected to one of
the tested fan sensors. (Note: not all motherboards have
the pwm outputs connected to the fan connectors,
check out the hardware database on http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php)
```

So it appears that it's able to find the fans, but not able to control them? How do I fix this?

I've also tried using [liquidctl](https://github.com/liquidctl/liquidctl) but that cannot find any fans to control either.

Here's the relevant part of the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1e71:201d NZXT NZXT Motherboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1e71:2011 NZXT NZXT RGB & Fan Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1e71:300c NZXT NZXT Kraken Elite
```

Lastly, I have tried to change the fan speed in the BIOS, but I couldn't find any such option, even in advanced settings.

Comment: try add "acpi_enforce_resources=lax" to cmdline at boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: use liquidctl ([Link](https://github.com/liquidctl/liquidctl))

Since the latest release of liquidctl (1.13.0) doesn't support my `NZXT RGB & Fan Controller` and `NZXT Kraken Elite` devices, I had to install with a git snapshot with the following:

```bash
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/liquidctl/liquidctl#egg=liquidctl
```

I then had to allow liquidctl to access the devices by adding a udev rule. I did this by adding this file ([Link](https://github.com/liquidctl/liquidctl/blob/main/extra/linux/71-liquidctl.rules)) to the directory `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/`

Finally I am able to control the Kraken fans and liquid pump speed, as well as two of the RGB fans (one of them is showing up as `control mode N/A` when I run `liquidctl status` - I'm willing to accept this for now)

Answer (score 0):

`hwmon3` is likely your motherboards Super I/O controller.  pwmconfig is not seeing anything else.

`NZXT Kraken Elite` This is an AIO and it probably what you are seeing on fan2_input.  It is powered directly from the PSU so changing the PWM speed for that input will not do anything.  It is also plugged into USB which is why lsusb sees it.  It has 2 fan connections and the fans on the radiator may be plugged into this.

`NZXT RGB & Fan Controller` This is another fan controller.  I'm not sure if this is a separate device or if it's also being reported as part of the AIO.  If it is a separate device, your fans are probably plugged into that, or a combination of the AIO and this.

`modprobe nzxt-smart2` should load the drivers for the `NZXT RGB & Fan Controller`, and hopefully you can get `pwmconfig` to see those fans.  If it does, you will need to add `nzxt-smart2` to `/etc/modules`.  If it doesn't work, you could always move the fans from the controller to the motherboard.  I'm not sure if NZXT has support for Linux that you could reach out to as well if you are having trouble.